# Why having NPE at jstl?

Tags: jstl

Do you have any ideea why having NPE for this?

```
<c:forEach
            var="css"
            items="${fn:split('test,test,', ',')}">
            <link
                rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css"
                href="${css}"></link>
        </c:forEach>
```

I simply don't understand why this is not correct.

```
 javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.Exception: javax.faces.FacesException: 
Problem in renderResponse: /WEB-INF/jsf/userapp-main.jsf @40,44 items="${fn:split('test,test,', ',')}" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems that I forgot to declare `fn`:

`xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"`

I would have expected something like `tag not defined` instead of a generic NPE.